# Two students play the game: firstly, A assigns integer numbers to the faces...probability game

Tags: probability, statistics

Two students play the game: firstly, A assigns integer numbers to the faces of 3 fair dice. At the second step B thoughtfully chooses one dice. At the third step, A chooses one of the two remaining. Finally, they roll their dice and the winner is the student who has got the larger number at her die. Who have better chances to win?

Comment: How depends the outcome from the original integers which were assigned by A?

Comment: You might want to read about [Non-transitive Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice).

Comment: What do you mean my that?

Comment: It depends:  did either A or B have a strategy in this, or are we supposed to assume each move is random.  If it's the former, I would kindly reccommend listing the details.  If it's the latter, they should have equal chances either way.  I was hesitant to this conclusion when I started thinking about the minty hall problem, but I soon realized that there is a bias to the Monty hall problem in the sense that you can only see a door that's not your's and doesn't have the prize behind it.  Assuming no bias to this problem, it would be 50/50.  Please comment, though if it isnt meant to be random.

Comment: @MathMachine Like Monty Hall, this problem's answer is counterintuitive. The link to non-transitive dice in the earlier comment includes a winning strategy for Player A.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments:  the answer to this problem is unintuitive.  On it's face it would appear that $B$ should have a winning strategy.  After all, all $B$ has to do is to figure out which one of the three dice is the best and then pick that one.

The mistake here lies in the assumption that dice are "transitive". That is, if die $1$ beats die $2$ (meaning it wins more than half the time) and die $2$ beats die $3$ then it is natural to imagine that this implies that $1$ beats $3$.  Surprisingly, this is false. It is possible to put numbers on the three die in such a way that the triple is non-transitive.  So that die $1$ beats $2$, $2$ beats $3$, but $3$ beats $1$.  This is discussed, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice).

This gives $A$ a winning strategy.  $A$ creates a triple of non-transitive dice, and then no matter what $B$ choses, $A$ can choose a better die.